# How to call all object from array through map method in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
[{
    "Table_Name13": "64",
    "Table_Name14": "65",
    "Table_Name15": "66",
    "Table_Name16": "67",
    "Table_Name17": "68",
    "Table_Name18": "69",
    "Table_Name19": "71",
    "Table_Name20": "72",
    "Table_Name21": "73",
    "Table_Name22": "74",
    "Table_Name23": "75",
    "Table_Name24": "76",
    "Table_Name25": "77",
    "Table_Name26": "78",
    "Table_Name27": "79",
    "Table_Name28": "",
    "Table_Name29": "60",
    "Table_Name30": "",
    "Table_Name31": ""
    
}]
```

I have this type of API JSON. So how to use `map` method to print all JSON data one by one in a page. If not map method , please suggest another method to print all JSON Data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Considered that your data is stored in `const jsondata` you could go like

```js
// use jsondata[0] because your data is inside an array
Object.keys(jsondata[0]).forEach(item => {
    console.log(`Key: ${item}`)
    console.log(`Data: ${jsondata[0][item]}`)
})
```